# Map mvc3 Model object to select2 plugin data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to map Model.property to the data of Select2 plugin with no luck, keep getting "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand result" in the console.

```
public class Items{
    public int id;
    public string text;
};
public class Model{
    ...
    public Items[] arr { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The Model is passed to the Razor partialview where my jsScript does some magic

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sel').select2({
            data: '@Model.arr',
            ...
    });
</script>
```

Everything looks ok until I click inside the select box to see the items in it. Then I get the console error I referred to earlier.

**Solution to my proplem:**

```
// Changed the property of Model class to string.
public class Model{
    ...
    public string arr { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

1. In the controller-> Create IList object and fill it with items.
2. In the controller-> Serialize the list object and put it into 'arr' property in Model class.
3. In the view
   select2({
       ...
       data: { results: eval('(@Html.Raw(Model.arr))') }
       ...
   })

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your list as IList, I had a similar problem and it worked:

```
public IList<Items> arr { get; set; }
```

And you have an obvious error because you don't specify the id and text to display in the box, like:

```
.select2({
data:[
{id:0,text:'item1'},
{id:1,text:'item2'},
{id:2,text:'item3'},
{id:3,text:'item4'},
{id:4,text:'item5'}
]});
```

So, you should be able to work around with:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sel').select2({
             data:{ results: '@Model.arr', text: 'text' }, // 'text' is the name of you model property with your text
             formatSelection: format,
             formatResult: format
    });
function format(item) { return item.text; };
</script>
```

If it dows not work, I suggest you start debugging by declairing a test array like the [official doc](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#data_array)

```
var data=[{id:0,tag:'enhancement'},{id:1,tag:'bug'},{id:2,tag:'duplicate'},{id:3,tag:'invalid'},{id:4,tag:'wontfix'}];
function format(item) { return item.tag; };

$("#e10_2").select2({
data:{ results: data, text: 'tag' },
formatSelection: format,
formatResult: format
});
```

If this code is not working, you will know that the error is coming from the Jquery and not your code

Comment: I tried all above but still getting this error: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand result
[Break On This Error]  

compound=("children" in result) && result.children.length > 0;

Comment: Try to add function format(item) { return item.text; };
in your script like I just updated in my answer...

Comment: I have tried this and it all works if I declare the array in the javascript. This has something to do with the object that I am passing to the javascript, the IList<Items>.